# app crashes with MapView if i use sdk 29 ------

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with MapView. My map was loaded correctly until I used "targetSdkVersion 19", but since I updated to "targetSdkVersion 29" every time I launch the map activity, the app crashes. 
Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?

```
2019-08-29 17:04:05.679 29021-29119/mcsistemi.tentatavendita E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
Process: mcsistemi.tentatavendita, PID: 29021
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
    at ce.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):3)
    at cb.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):3)
    at cd.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):14)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ak.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):4)
    at bf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):22)
    at bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):8)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000c6/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000c6/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):4)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at ce.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):3) 
    at cb.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):3) 
    at cd.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):14) 
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ak.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):4) 
    at bf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):22) 
    at bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19056081@19.0.56 (100400-262933554):8)
```

Comment: Check log cat and provide crash report with question .

Comment: done, sorry....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this under `<application>` tag in `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

> With Android 6.0, we removed support for the Apache HTTP client.
>   Beginning with Android 9, that library is removed from the
>   bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default.
>
> To continue using the Apache HTTP client, apps that target Android 9
>   and above can add the above line to their AndroidManifest.xml:

Here is more [info](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28)
 by Google

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it started after android sdk 29, the problem could also be from the fact that you haven't changed your mappings to the current androidx mappings in the **layout file** that bring up this problem

If there is a library call like ***android.support.v7.widget.CardView*** in your layout causing the problem, you must change it to ***androidx.cardview.widget.CardView*** in android X and sdk 29 upwards..

For more mappings and how its currently written in the layout files, kindly check this link for the other class mappings https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings