# "Debugging" an android app after it has been deployed to the store

Tags: android

I have deployed an Android app (that utilises maps) on the Google Play Store and all my friends who have got it say it works fine, except for one user, who is on a Samsung S9 running Android 9. He says that the app crashes as soon as the launcher icon is pressed. I'm at a loss as to how to proceed since the app works fine on my machine and on everyone elses, as far as I can determine. How can I proceed? Is there a way to run the app on his machine to generate a trace or some logs to determine when/how the crash occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Fabric, It's free and doing awesome job. now Fabric joined forces with Firebase with the goal of giving developers one place to build and grow their apps. Now that we've brought over the Fabric tools you know and love to Firebase, Fabric will deprecating on March 31, 2020 and terminating all Fabric service agreements at that time. so you can check Firebase too.

And also from your `Google Play Console` -> `Select you app` -> `Android Vitals` -> `ARNs & craches` and here you can also find some useful informations about craches (The activity and the line number)

Comment: Many thanks, I'd rarely used this facility before and while it didn't tell me about line number, it told me that the problem lay in "com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite", and a search on stackoverflow revealed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712884/app-crashes-with-mapview-if-i-use-sdk-29

Answer (score 0):

I use [firebase crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics). Crashlytics creates a full report about any bug that your app suffers. It is very easy to implement and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Crashlytics is [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). It's still actively maintained and you can [host the stack by yourself](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Report-Destinations) or use [one of the provided solutions](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends).